# Unity: Xcode 10.1 app signing does not work for free account

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I cannot delpoy Unity game to my phone because of following errors:

- Your development team, "Team Name", does not support the Game Center capability. (in target 'Unity-iPhone')
- No profiles for 'com.Bundle.Name' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.Bundle.Name'. (in target 'Unity-iPhone')

I'm using Personal Team (free for iOS development) and already tried to retrive new certificate for it.

Any ideas what is happening an how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that game center is disabled in the capabilities tab.

Comment: @JeanLuc there is no such capability available on the tab https://imgur.com/a/UHHLfia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable Game Center capability for Personal Team you first need to set Signing Team to None - this will show all the possible capabilities on appropriate tab.
After disabling Game Center you can go back and choose Personal Team - app will now be signed successfully.